# Как вписать картинки в модульную сетку

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такое понятие вертикальный ритм, которое предполагает, что все вертикальные отступы на странице пропорциональны определенному числу, например размеру шрифта 16px или 1em. В результате вся верстка красиво ложиться на сетку и отлично выглядит. Но, когда мы вставляем картинку нестандартных размеров, все что ниже едет мимо сетки и, если у нас многоколоночный сайт, — это становится заметно.

Собственно вопрос: как *подрезать* картинки на странице, чтобы их ширина и высота всегда были кратны (делились нацело на 16) шагу сетки? При этом хочется сохранить адаптивность, т.е. чтобы размер картинок менялся на лету дискретно.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

body {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent 23px, gray 24px),repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,transparent 23px, gray 24px);
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.375em;
  line-height: 1.26315789em;
  margin-top: 0.63157895em;
  margin-bottom: 1.2631579em;
}

p {
   margin-top: 0em;
   margin-bottom: 1.5em;
   max-width: 552px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis libero magni ex nam, aliquid minus officiis, at impedit enim voluptatum tempora qui quisquam mollitia aperiam ullam cum soluta distinctio voluptatem.</p>
<p>Adipisci veritatis libero tempora, consequatur qui atque autem magni assumenda eius reiciendis nam soluta aliquid, eum optio dignissimos. Eveniet, eaque. Numquam error inventore, hic soluta fugit sed aspernatur maiores deleniti.</p>
<p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-600-375-9.jpg"></p>
<p>Soluta ad rem excepturi eos temporibus molestiae iusto optio earum sit, odit minima quis nulla deleniti. Labore aperiam qui reiciendis a, distinctio eligendi fugit, fugiat tenetur incidunt quod libero id!</p>
```